# A simple lemma in tensor product

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Here is a quotation of a book: ($\otimes$ denotes the minimal tensor product)

> **Lemma 3.9.2.** Let $A$ be a C*-algebra. If $E\subset A$ is an operator system and $J\triangleleft B$ is an ideal, then there is an isometric inclusion
>   $$\frac{E\otimes B}{E \otimes J} \subset \frac{A\otimes B} {A\otimes J}$$.
>
> **Proof.** We must show that if $x\in E\otimes B$, then its norm down in $\frac{A\otimes B}{A\otimes J}$ is equal to 
>   $$\inf\{||x+y||: y\in E\otimes J\}.$$
>
> This is easily seen since the norm in $\frac{A\otimes B}{A\otimes J}$ is equal to $$\lim||x(1\otimes(1-e_{i}))||,$$
>   where $\{e_{i}\}$ is an approximate unit for $J$.

**My question is** why "the norm in $\frac{A\otimes B}{A\otimes J}$ is equal to $\lim||x(1\otimes(1-e_{i}))||$" above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By definition, for $x\in A\otimes B$,
$$
\|x+A\otimes J\|=\inf\{\|x-y\|:\ y\in A\otimes J\}.
$$
Now, for $y\in A\otimes J$, 
$$
x-y=\lim_j (x-y(1\otimes e_j))=\lim_j\,x(1\otimes (1-e_j))+(x-y)(1\otimes e_j).
$$
The elements inside the limit are of the form $x(1\otimes (1-e_j))+z$, $z\in A\otimes J$. Thus
$$
\|x+A\otimes J\|=\inf\{\lim_j\|x(1\otimes (1-e_j))+(x-y)(1\otimes e_j)\|:\ y\in A\otimes J\}\\
=\lim_j\|x(1\otimes(1-e_j))\|
$$
(note that we can take $y=x(1\otimes e_k)$ for $k$ arbitrarily large).

The inspiration for this is easier for me to see in the von Neumann algebra case. If $M$ is a vN algebra and $J\subset M$ a ultraweakly closed ideal, then $J=pM$ for some central projection $p\in M$. Then
$$
\|x+J\|=\text{dist}(x,J)=\inf\{\|x-py\|:\ y\in M\}=\inf\{\|x(1-p)+(x-y)p\|:\ y\in M\}\\
=\inf\{\max\{\|x(1-p)\|,\|(x-y)p\|\}:\ y\in M\,\}=\|x(1-p)\|
$$
(note that the infimum is taken over number all greater than or equal $\|x(1-p)\|$, and this number is achieved when $y=x$).

Comment: But $A$ may be a non-unital C*-algebra, if $A$ is non-unital, what does the "1" denote here?

Comment: Good question. They are likely taking $A$ as unital since the operator system is unital. And apparently $B$ too. I'll have to think about it.